# FileNotFoundException: path syntax wrong

Tags: java, eclipse, filereader

I am trying to export my project as an executable jar file in eclipse.
My jar file looks like this:
\com
\de
\org
\res

I've got some xml files in the res folder and now I have some problems getting these files with the FileReader

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jar:file:\C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\Brainwav3.jar!\res\de.xml (Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at de.brainwav3.language.LanguageHandler.load(LanguageHandler.java:98)
    at de.brainwav3.core.Launch.main(Launch.java:24)
```

The path gets generated like this:

```
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/res/de.xml");

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(url.toString());
```

So I don't really have control over the path.

I resolved this problem with copying the required files next to the jar file and changing the url to another path but I want all ressources to be inside the jar file

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files and you can't use things like `FileReader` on them. Use `getResourceAsStream`

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. Works like a charm